# How do you print to a text file in GAP without linebreaks?

Tags: gap-system

Minimum working example:

```gap
x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");
f:=Sum([1..1000],i->x^i);
PrintTo("~/temp.txt",f);
```

It prints to `temp.txt` the following:

```gap
x^1000+x^999+x^998+x^997+x^996+x^995+x^994+x^993+x^992+x^991+x^990+x^989+x^988\
+x^987+x^986+x^985+x^984+x^983+x^982+x^981+x^980+x^979+x^978+x^977+x^976+x^975\
+x^974+x^973+x^972+x^971+x^970+x^969+x^968+x^967+x^966+x^965+x^964+x^963+x^962\
+x^961+x^960+x^959+x^958+x^957+x^956+x^955+x^954+x^953+x^952+x^951+x^950+x^949\

[snip]
```

How can I instead get it to print it on a single line in the text file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a common need, and the solution is called `SetPrintFormattingStatus`. See [its documentation online](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap10.html#X8663FCD57E8BC390)
or just type `?SetPrintFormattingStatus` in the GAP prompt to see the documentation.

Note that you will have to use streams in this case, it does not work
with text files straightforwardly. `OutputTextFile` (documented just after
`SetPrintFormattingStatus`) is what you need to use.

In the example above, use

```gap
x:=Indeterminate(Rationals,"x");
f:=Sum([1..1000],i->x^i);
output := OutputTextFile( "poly", false );;
SetPrintFormattingStatus(output, false);
PrintTo(output,f);
```